# nginx throws a 404 for files that exist on the path

Tags: nginx

I'm having a weird issue with nginx. I'm using version 1.8.0 And using the web server address I can successfully serve files from the web server address, but not from the web site address!

Web server address: aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com
Web site address: stg.showdb.vod.example.com

I have a server block setup like this:

```
  server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com stg.showdb.vod.example.com stg.showdb.vod;

        location / {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            access_log  logs/stg.showdb.vod.access.log;
            error_log  logs/stg.showdb.vod.error.log;
        }

        location  ^/videos/ {
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            error_log  logs/videos_error.log;
        }
    }
```

And I have a directory with files in it beneath the 'video' location. NGINX is running as a user called 'showdb’, so the files are owned by that user:

```
[root@aoaapls00109la ~]# ls -ld /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos
drwxr-xr-x. 3 showdb showdb 4096 Nov 18 13:25 /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos

     [root@aoaapls00109la ~]# ls -lh /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos
total 2.8G
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb 738M May 12  2015 1681_Scarlett_Johansson_Repeat.mp4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb  30K May 11  2015 200X200.jpg
-rw-r--r--. 1 showdb showdb  260 Nov 18 10:44 crossdomain.xml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb 238M May 12  2015 some_guy_TS_0260-05122015.mp4
-rw-r--r--. 1 showdb showdb   63 Jun  3 07:10 index.html
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb 302M May 12  2015 LNWSM_101314_SHOW0112_med_clean.mp4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb 864M May  5  2015 LNWSM_101314_SHOW0112.mp4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb 331M May 12  2015 LNWSM_101314_SHOW0112_sm_clean.mp4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb  23K May 15  2015 some_guy_logo.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb 391M May 15  2015 RK119_EP_0514-15.mp4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb  24K May  8  2015 SNL_40_COMPANY_16x9_1_SNL.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 showdb showdb 160K May 12  2015 TSJF_LOGO.png
drwxrwxr-x. 5 showdb showdb 4.0K Nov 19 15:17 webvtt_files
```

And I notice that if I use the first dns name for the web server itself, I can successfully navigate and view the contents of the 'videos' folder.

Demonstrating with curl, I can access files from the videos directory using the web server name addresss:

```
#curl http://aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com/videos/index.html
Video Store located on the server aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com
```

But if I use the website address, instead of accessing the index file like above I get a 404!!

```
 curl http://stg.showdb.vod.example.com/videos/index.html
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And the same behavior happens for the all the files in the 'videos' directory. And worse yet, the files that aren't being served and that are showing the 404's are not generating any activity in either the access or the error logs!

And if I bring up the same files from the web server address in one tab on my browser, I can see the same location giving a 404 for the same exact file that's being shown successfully under the web server address.

Here's the whole nginx config, in case that may have some clues as to why this is happening:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
#
user showdb;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }



    }

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com stg.showdb.vod.example.com stg.showdb.vod;

        location / {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            access_log  logs/stg.showdb.vod.access.log;
            error_log  logs/stg.showdb.vod.error.log;
        }

        location  ^/videos/ {
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            error_log  logs/videos_error.log;
        }
    }


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name   stg.cdn.showsys.example.com stg.cdn.showsystem.example.com;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
          location / {
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            access_log  logs/stg.cdn.showsys.access.log;
            error_log  logs/videos_error.log;
        }
    }

server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name   stg.showdb.vod.example.com stg.showdb.vod;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/pki/tls/certs/aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            access_log  logs/stg.showdb.vod.access.log;
            error_log  logs/stg.showdb.vod.error.log;
        }

        location /videos/ {
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            error_log  logs/videos_error.log;
        }
    }

server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  stg.cdn.showsys.example.com stg.cdn.showsystem.example.com;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/pki/tls/certs/aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/aoaapls00109la.stg-example.com.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";

          location / {
            root   /opt/www/webserver/nginx/html/videos;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            access_log  logs/stg.cdn.showsys.access.log;
            error_log  logs/videos_error.log;
        }
    }
```

This is very baffling!! What am I doing wrong? And how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a RegEx match, don't forget your tilde (or `~*` for case-insensitive RegEx).  RegEx matches trump non-RegEx matches

```
location ~  ^/videos/ {
  ...
}
```

Remove the tilde if you're not intending a RegEx match

```
location /videos/ {
  ...
}
```